# org.json.JSONException: No value for

Tags: java, android, json

*EDIT:

So I've asked the PHP Guy, and yes he forgot to write the `"fullname"` string in his code. Sorry for my mistake.

I'm new in Java Android, so a lil bit confuse about this code. What I'm trying to do is get the value, but it always whot this error in Android Studio :

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for fullname
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.skafen.bayarin.ServerRequests$fetchUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:130)
W/System.err:     at com.skafen.bayarin.ServerRequests$fetchUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:93)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And the java is :

```
public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> { //line #93

        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;

        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");


            User returnedUser = null;
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse =  client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if (jObject.length() == 0 ){
                    returnedUser = null;
                }else {
                    String fullname = jObject.getString("fullname"); //line #130
                    int birthday = jObject.getInt("birthday");
                    String email = jObject.getString("email");

                    returnedUser = new User(fullname, birthday, email, user.username, user.password);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(returnedUser);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the attention, and sorry if I post a new thread with same topic because I'm new here.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, does the JSON contain fullname? Print `result` to check it

Comment: Yes, we need the json string, please post that

Comment: I don't get what you'll mean, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Print the variable `jObject` and add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to get value called "fullname" that doesn't even exist in HttpResponse. Make sure the responsed json contains a key called "fullname" (telling server guy) and try again.

Comment: Okay, I will ask the PHP Guy. Thank you.

Comment: make sure you see the json first in debugging mode. If that's "full_name" or "FULL_NAME" instead of "fullname", this will be your fault.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, and yes the PHP guy forgot to write the code. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 5):

use

```
jsonObject.optString("SELECTOR");
```

insted of

```
jsonObject.getString("SELECTOR");
```