# org.json.JSONException: No value for {...}

Tags: java, android, json, exception

I'm not sure why I'm getting an exception, but no matter what I have in my JSON file, Android doesn't seem to be able to parse it.

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for {"name":"Test 1"}
```

Here's the JSON file, pretty simple stuff:

```
{"name":"Test 1"}
```

And the relevant Java:

```
    public WritingTest readTestFromFile(Context context) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String json;
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open("WritingTest1.json")));
        while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(json);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        Log.v("Stringbuilder Output", stringBuilder.toString());
        String jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
        object.getJSONObject(jsonString);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("IOException", "Something went wrong with opening the file.");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("JSONException", "Something went wrong with JSON reader");
    } finally {
        return new WritingTest(object);
    }
}
```

And finally the error code:

```
V/Stringbuilder Output: {"name":"Test 1"}
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for {"name":"Test 1"}
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
W/System.err:     at com.holospring.prodigept.WritingSelectorFragment.readTestFromFile(WritingSelectorFragment.java:80)
W/System.err:     at com.holospring.prodigept.WritingSelectorFragment.onActivityCreated(WritingSelectorFragment.java:44)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1983)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:174)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Granted, I don't have much experience with JSON, it checks as valid, so I'm assuming it's something in my Java code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing in android: No value for x error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947065/json-parsing-in-android-no-value-for-x-error)

Comment: You try to access the property named `{"name":"Test 1"}`. You have to put the JSON String into the constructor: `new JSONObject(jsonString)`. Then you can access the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this link:
[Decoding JSON in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

The point is that you have to parse JSON first, then access the fields. What you do is that you create an empty JSONObject and then try to access field with name `{"name":"Test 1"}`

Something like this should do:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject object = (JSONObject)parser.parse(jsonString);
String name = object.getString("name");
```

Comment: Yep, I can see what I did wrong now.

    object.getJSONObject(jsonString);

should be

    object = new JSONObject(jsonString);


Dumb mistake on my part. Been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 0):

you can use optString() instead of  getString() in JsonObject. You can see the detailed answer below :

[org.json.JSONException: No value for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846823/org-json-jsonexception-no-value-for/37584199#37584199)